# when parsing json how to make a button load a url from the json?

Tags: ios, xcode, json, mpmovieplayercontroller

How would I code it so that when I press a UIButton it will play a video from a mobile_url?
 I am adapting a twitter json api feed grabber to grab my vimeo json api feed, The code below is how I parser the feed down for the labels but how would I make it so that each cell of the master view will change the link for a button like it does for the labels. In the json the url is @"mobile_url".

I have

```
NSDictionary *tweet = self.detailItem;   
NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"title"];   
NSString *name = [tweet objectForKey:@"description"];   
NSString *tags = [tweet objectForKey:@"tags"];  
NSString *date = [tweet objectForKey:@"upload_date"];  

nameLabel.text = text;  
tweetLabel.text = name;  
tagsLabel.text = tags;  
dateLabel.text = date;
```

the labels work great. but do I need to use something like this and more to pull up a in app video.

```
  NSString *playUrl = [tweet objectForKey:@"mobile_url"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code doesn't seem to be very relevant to what you're asking, but assuming that you know the URL that you wish to open it can be done with `UIApplication`'s `openURL`.

To open a URL with a button simply link this action to your button.

```
- (IBAction)openMyURL:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myURLstring"]];
}
```